Не могу найти решение проблему с cryptsetup в kali linux
Мне нужно зашифровать том диска для создания постоянного хранилища в kali linux. Адрес к нужному тому /dev/sdb3.
Ввожу команду cryptsetup --verbose --verify-passphrase luksFormat /dev/sdb3, которая мне возвращает после подтверждения действия
Operation aborted. Command failed with code -1 (wrong or missing parameters).
Все параметры вроде введены верно, не понимаю что может быть пропущено. Смотрел в документацию, вроде все нужные параметры ввел. Подскажите, что делаю не так, как исправить

--verfiy-passphrase - вводите дважды одну и ту же секретную фразу?
